# Upper triangular kernel initializer in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I wonder if there is a kernel initializer in Keras that initializes the kernel with random values, except that the low-left values are initialized as   zeros. I want to use that in a custom Keras layer in add_weights method. Or maybe a reliable TensorFlow operation? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked through the docs? https://keras.io/initializers/

Comment: P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

## Methods:

You can define your own initializer. And use the `np.triu()` to create an upper triangular kernel.

## A small example:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def my_init(shape, dtype=None):
    init = tf.random_normal(shape, dtype=dtype)
    return np.triu(init)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 256, kernel_initializer=my_init, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), kernel_initializer=my_init, padding='same', use_bias=False))
```